# Update Wordpress with SFTP instead of FTP

Tags: upgrade, updates

Is there a way to update Wordpress without the use of FTP, but with SFTP (which uses SSH)? I've only got my server set up for SSH access (and therefore SCP/SFTP).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Configuration instructions in Codex on [Enabling SSH Upgrade Access](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#enabling-ssh-upgrade-access) recommend either:

1. Using [SSH SFTP Updater Support](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssh-sftp-updater-support/) plugin from official repository.
2. Using built–in SSH2 support, which requires the PECL SSH2 extension installed on the server.

It used to refer to this tutorial: [Using SSH to Install/Upgrade](http://www.jonathan.vc/wordpress-install-upgrade-ssh.html) in before, which might be of use.

Comment: More recently, the SSH SFTP updater appears to be abandoned and no longer supported (last update is more than two years ago). Are there any other options?

Comment: @CharlesTryon, the `SSH SFTP Updater Support` plugin does not seem to be abandoned; as of this writing the last update was 2 months ago according to the wordpress plugin repo. I've also recently used the plugin and can report that it is indeed working.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it quite easily with this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ssh-sftp-updater-support/

Comment: [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion).